# A Button to make a TextView from invisible to visible

Tags: xcode

iam a newbie in Xcode programming and i didnt find the right answer in another Tread.
My Question: I have a Detailview with a CardQuestion(TextView) and a CardAnser(TextView).
How is the method to change the invisible Answer to visible.
On Action the Button "Show Answer".

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];

self.title = self.chosenCard.name;
self.cardName.text = self.chosenCard.name;
self.cardQuestion.text = self.chosenCard.question;
self.cardAnswer.text = self.chosenCard.answer;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[self setCardName:nil];
[self setCardQuestion:nil];
[self setCardAnswer:nil];
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (IBAction)toAnswerButton:(id)sender{


}
@end
```

I hope you can understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

`UIView` subviews (including `UILabel`, `UITextField` and `UITextView`) have a hidden property. Set that to `YES` to hide a view and to `NO` to unhide it. You can also set this property in Interface Builder.

Comment: hey, yes i know. But i want that the User activate the "toAnswerButton" and then the answer becomes visible.

Comment: I want to know what i have to write in the Buttonmethod. `- (IBAction)toAnswerButton:(id)sender { }`

I want to use the button for activate the visability. At beginning my TextView `cardAnswer` is invisible. If the User pushs the button, the TextView should becomes visible.
I dont know the correct method for it.

Comment: I can't write your app for you, sorry. [Your First iOS App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/JumpRightIn/iPhone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-TP40007514)

Comment: a link to a similar question would be enough ;), but ty

Comment: got it, self.cardAnswer.hidden = No;